# Which requirements in Embed.ly are necessary to build a https IFrame from a http website?

Tags: iframe, https, embedly

How can I make

http://ida.bkg.bund.de/IVS/inc/GSB/ITRFstationcoord.php?name=x

a http**s** iframe with embed.ly?

I cannot choose "IFrame". This button is grey and a help text box is black with no text:

[image: embed.ly]

Comment: I am also having this issue.